# gradle: Task :jar SKIPPED while I get my jar with gradlew build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, manifest, gradlew

My Question is: Why does the jar-creation work with gradlew build, while I see "Task :jar SKIPPED" when I click on jar in intellij's gradle window ? And how can I fix it in IntelliJ ?

- Just created something with spring initializer and loaded the project in intellij as it is.
  ( it is org.springframework.boot, .. 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
- I wonder about Task :jar SKIPPED ( nor jar created )
- and than I discovered that I get the jar when I start  from console.
- ( and the jar runs fine, it finds the main class - even without jar manifest attribute in build.gradle)

( yesterday I failed in maven with "no main manifest attribute in .... .jar )

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly have you tried so far? Is your project using Gradle or Maven? what commands did you run and how? Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to clarify your question.

Answer (score 17):

This is because Springboot Gradle plugin will create a `bootJar` task and by default will disable `jar` and `war` tasks, as described here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal

So you need to execute `bootJar` task , from the IDE.  When executing `gradlew build`, the tasks `bootJar` gets automatically executed, due to tasks dependencies created by the plugin.

When running task `build` (from console or IDE), you can see the tasks executed by Gradle depending on tasks dependencies, e.g.:

```
> Task :backend:compileJava
> Task :backend:processResources
> Task :backend:classes
> Task :backend:bootJar      ## <== this is the task register by Springboot plugin, which produces the "Fat/executable" jar
> Task :backend:jar SKIPPED  ## <== task disabled by Springboot plugin
> Task :backend:assemble
> Task :backend:processTestResources
> Task :backend:testClasses
> Task :backend:test
> Task :backend:check
> Task :backend:build
```

For your remark

> the jar runs fine, it finds the main class - even without jar manifest
> attribute in build.gradle

The Springboot plugin will automatically configure this for you, see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class

**EDIT 27-05-2021**
Starting from Springboot 2.5, the `jar`is not disabled by default anymore. see more details in release notes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#gradle-default-jar-and-war-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You can enble this, with add code below in projectName.gradle
it works for me :

- spring-boot :  2.0.8.RELEASE
- Gradle : 4.5 or >

  jar {
  baseName = 'projectName'
  enabled=true

manifest {
....
}
}