# Springboot app not detecting the application properties file when the application is packaged as jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have a Springboot Gradle project. The application is up and running perfectly in the IDE. But when I package it as jar and run the jar file, application is not detecting the `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) file properties. I had to explicitly to add `@PropertySource` to read the `application.properties`. I feel there is some issue with the application packaging. Here is my Gradle plugins.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            mavenLocal()
            url <Maven Repo>
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.6.RELEASE"
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.2"

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id "application"
    id "jacoco"

}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

Any leads on this issue helpful.

[image: My application structure]

Comment: Can you post a structure of your project src/main, resources...?

Comment: Which jar file do you run exactly, the regular `jar`, the `bootJar` or the `shadowJar`?

Comment: @RenatoIvancic Added the Application structure.

Comment: @thokuest I run the regular jar

Comment: Does it work with `bootJar`?

Comment: @dan1st I just ran the `bootJar` and the Application is up and running.

Comment: I removed the `application` plugin, now the `jar` created is able to read the `application.properties`. Can anyone help me what is wrong with the `application` plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you managed to run **jar** task when having also **org.springframework.boot** plugin in the gradle buildscript. As [spring boot plugin should disable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-and-normal) jar task from java plugin. [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360840/gradle-task-jar-skipped-while-i-get-my-jar-with-gradlew-build).

If you have overriden this and you would want to generate working jar you would still need to configure that the libraries would be included or pass them to the java command.

So basically if you work with spring application the standard approach is to use **bootJar** Gradle task which will generate jar file which [Spring Boot classloader will be able to process](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-classloader-and-class-override#:%7E:text=spring%20boot%20loader%20classes%20both%20project%20classes%20%28boot-inf%2Fclasses%29,resides%20in%20the%20root%20of%20the%20jar%20%28org.springframework.boot.loader.launchedurlclassloader%29.). As @dan1st mentioned in the comment.

See Spring Boot packaged jar has different structure than normal jar:

```
+--- spring-boot-jar-0.0.1-snapshot.jar
     +--- meta-inf
     +--- boot-inf
     |    +--- classes                            # 1 Project Classes
     |    |     +--- com.rivancic.boot
     |    |     |    +--- SpringJarApplication.class
     |    |     |
     |    |     \--- application.properties
     |    |
     |    +--- lib                                # 2 Nested Jar Libraries
     |          +--- attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
     |          +--- jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar
     |          \--- ...
     |
     +--- org.springframework.boot.loader         # 3 Spring Boot Loader Classes
          +--- jarlauncher.class
          +--- launchedurlclassloader.class
          \--- ...
```

Normal Jar:

```
+--- jar-0.0.1-snapshot.jar
     +--- meta-inf  
     +--- com.rivancic.boot                       # 1 Project Classes
     |    +--- SpringJarApplication.class
     |
     \--- application.properties
```

Comment: `bootJar` if you're using Spring Boot